# Почему программа построенная в C++ Builder 10.2 Community ломается, а построенная в C++ Builder 6.0 нет?

Tags: c++builder

Трудный вопрос.
Есть своя библиотека построенная на mingw-32 - набор DLL.
Решил сделать программу с GUI, все вычисления проводятся в моих библиотеках а не в коде C++ Builder.

По быстрому установил старый Borland C++ Builder 6.0, написал wrapper (ещё 1 DLL ) чтобы программа имела доступ к библиотеке. В общем всё работает.

Программа запускает wrapper.dll
wrapper.dll запускает mylib.dll
ok, всё работает.

Скачал бесплатный лицензионный C++ Builder, программа компилируется, но ломается, в моменте когда wrapper.dll запускает mylib.dll

Быть может в настройках стоят какие флаги, или ещё что-то, что не позволяет запустить библиотеку.
Может в этом и заключается Community версия, ибо старый билдер был крякнутой профессиональной версией.

В общем вот код.

```
//================================================================
//                     Это код C++ Builder
//================================================================
#include <vcl.h>
#pragma hdrstop
#include "Unit1.h"
#pragma package(smart_init)
#pragma resource "*.dfm"

// Функции которые будут импортированы из wrapper
// Параметр не важен
typedef int (*init_mylib_t)( unsigned int hwnd_address );
typedef int (*shutdown_mylib_t)();

struct Wrapper{
    Wrapper():
        m_lib( 0 ),
        m_init_mylib_f( 0 ),
        m_shutdown_mylib_f( 0 )
    {}

    ~Wrapper(){
        if( m_lib ){
            FreeLibrary( m_lib );
        }
    }

    HMODULE           m_lib;
    init_mylib_t       m_init_mylib_f;
    shutdown_mylib_t   m_shutdown_mylib_f;
};

//Так я избавился от использования глобальной переменной Wrapper
//может можно как проще, незнаю, но вопрос не в этом
unsigned long long & __getWrapper(){
    static unsigned long long address = 0u;
    return address;
}

Wrapper* getWrapper(){
        return (Wrapper*)__getWrapper();
}

void setWrapper( Wrapper * wrapper ){
    __getWrapper() = (unsigned long long)((void*)wrapper);
}

//Загрузка враппера, получение адресов и запуск библиотеки
void init_wrapper( unsigned int button_hwnd ){
    Wrapper* wrapper = new Wrapper;
    setWrapper( wrapper );

    wrapper->m_lib = LoadLibrary( L"wrapper.dll" );
    if( !wrapper->m_lib ){
        throw Exception("Can not load wrapper.dll");
    }

    wrapper->m_init_mylib_f = (init_mylib_t)GetProcAddress( wrapper->m_lib, "init_mylib" );
    if( !wrapper->m_init_mylib_f ){
        throw Exception("Can not get procedure address [init_mylib] from wrapper.dll");
    }

    wrapper->m_shutdown_mylib_f = (shutdown_mylib_t)GetProcAddress( wrapper->m_lib, "shutdown_mylib" );
    if( !wrapper->m_shutdown_mylib_f ){
        throw Exception("Can not get procedure address [shutdown_mylib] from wrapper.dll");
    }
    //запуск библиотеки
    if( !wrapper->m_init_mylib_f( button_hwnd ) ){
        throw Exception("Can not init mylib");
    }
}

TForm1 *Form1;
__fastcall TForm1::TForm1(TComponent* Owner): TForm(Owner){}
void __fastcall TForm1::FormDestroy(TObject *Sender){
      shutdown_wrapper();
}
void __fastcall TForm1::FormCreate(TObject *Sender){
     init_wrapper( (unsigned int)Button1->Handle );
}
```

wrapper.dll

```
extern "C"{

MYLIB_API int init_mylib( unsigned int hwnd_address ){
    auto wrapper = getWrapper();

    //выполняя этот метод, wrapper.dll вызывает mylib.dll
    //при инициализации mylib.dll программа перестаёт работать
    // hwnd_address равен 0 
    if( !wrapper->init( hwnd_address ) )    return 0;

        return 1;
    }

    MYLIB_API int shutdown_mylib(){
        return 1;
    }
}
```

.exe вызывает wrapper.dll явно

wrapper.dll вызывает mylib.dll неявно

Смотреть код библиотеки нет смысла из за огромных размеров, она рабочая, компилируется со всеми предупреждениями на различных GCC компиляторах и Visual Studio, все недочёты устранены и т.д.

Старый билдер строит и программа работает. Почему не строит рабочую программу современный билдер?

В новом билдере сначала я написал всё с нуля. Думал в этом проблема, что-то забыл.
Но потом протестировал на старом, там всё работает.

Ломается так.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: _ломается_ - что именно происходит?

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov дополнил вопрос.